# finding a transpose matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

```
sample = MatrixForm[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1.2], {3, 2, 2}]]
Tranp = Transpose[MatrixForm[sample]]
```

This is my attempt to find the transpose of three matrices, which have 2 by 2.
I want to transpose three matrices, but Mathematica does not show transpose matrices of them.
Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `MatrixForm` if you want to do further computations. It is only a display wrapper. Try removing it from your code altogether. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/27951).

Comment: `MatrixForm[]` is exactly the reason why you are not able to transpose your matrices. Try `Transpose /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1.2], {3, 2, 2}]`.

Comment: Thanx. However, I got
{{{-0.904744, 0.780324}, {-0.23862, -1.1759}}, {{-3.66135, 
   0.522371}, {-1.73903, -1.37296}}, {{0.211416, 
   1.38779}, {-1.1991, -0.568966}}}
Its transpose is 
{{{-0.904744, 0.780324}, {-3.66135, 0.522371}, {0.211416, 
   1.38779}}, {{-0.23862, -1.1759}, {-1.73903, -1.37296}, {-1.1991, \
-0.568966}}}

Comment: What isn't its transpose like 
{{{-0.904744, -0.23862}, {-1.1759, 0.522371}, {0.211416, 
   -0.23862}}, {{1.38779, -1.1759}, {-1.73903, -1.1991}, {-1.37296, \
-0.568966}}}?

Comment: Bora first, please update your question with such information. It is useless to leave it in the comments and it is better for future users to update your question with this information. Second, when performing random calculations it is helpful to include a `SeedRandom` so that they are reproducible by those that wish to help you.

Comment: Bora, your expected output is missing terms from the original matrix you indicate. Certainly that is not a transposed matrix, then. It will be helpful to clarify what you mean by a “transpose” operation, as it does not follow the definition of the transpose operation.